# How to achieve multiple combinations of JCombobox in java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have 4 comboboxes...client.sengg,month,product and 1 JTable...so when I select any item from client want to display row in Jtable which contains these selected item..if I select sengg and product then values against this items want to display...if select client,month,product then these values should be displays...so currently only client is displays, So how to achieve it?

```
            try
            {

                String query="Select * from enquiry where `client` =? or `Sales`=? or `month`=? or `Product`= ? " ;

                PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1,(String) client.getSelectedItem());
                pst.setString(2,(String) sengg.getSelectedItem());
                pst.setString(3,(String) product.getSelectedItem());
                pst.setString(4,(String) month.getSelectedItem());
                ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();


                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                //return; 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Or query is right for it?

Comment: Please, inform your Exception: 
in catch area: e.printStackTrace();

Comment: yes..I did...but is it right code to fetch data from combobox...because here i got only client and sales value...but want all 4 combinations